# R > openxlsx::read.xlsx treats values and formulae differently

Tags: r

When using `openxlsx::read.xlsx` in R, I am getting different results, reading values in an Excel file vs. reading formulas.

If you save an xlsx workbook as 'test.xlsx' with the following formulas in cells A1:A3:

| A |
| --- |
| Col1 |
| A & B |
| =A2 |

Then in R:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tibble)
my_file <- openxlsx::read.xlsx('test.xlsx')
tibble::view(my_file)
```

Then you should see:

| `Col1` |
| --- |
| `A & B` |
| `A &amp; B` |

Does anyone know how to change the `&amp;` back into an `&` (without modifying the original xlsx)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `stringr` you can modify the "&" which is generated from the excel formula reading the file with `read.xlsx`

```r
library(openxlsx)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

read.xlsx("test.xlsx") %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = str_replace(Col1, "&amp;", "&"))
#>    Col1
#> 1 A & B
#> 2 A & B
```

Alternatively you could avoid the issue altogether by using `readxl` to read the file.

```
library(readxl)

read_xlsx('test.xlsx')
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   Col1 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 A & B
#> 2 A & B
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>